# Correlation in a directed graph - R

Tags: r, networking, graph, correlation

I have a directed graph in the following format that each pair (row) indicates an edge from source to the target

```
Source  Target
364 448
364 449
364 371
364 372
534 743
534 371
```

I need to calculate the correlation (kind of dependency) for each pair. I already made the adjunct matrix for the mentioned format and try to calculate the Correlation and Covariance based on [1](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/correlations.html). The result that I got was not correct.

R or any other free tool which can be used for it is fine.

Any Solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe more precisely the format of your data ? You have vectors associated to each node, right ?

Comment: @Math. I edited the question. Anyway, Basically each pair (row) indicates an edge from source to the target (i.e. directed)

Comment: Can you show what you tried ? (your code, plus the result you got, and the result you expect)